# Functional for estimating upwards by derivation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $g\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$ with bounded derivation. Is there a functional/mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}\times\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$|\ |g(x)|-|g(y)|\ |\leq \phi(x-y,g')$$ holds?

I know that for the special case that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}:g(x)\geq0$ the problem is easy to solve by $$|g(x)-g(y)|=|\int_0^1 g'(y+t(x-y))\cdot (x-y)\mathrm{d}t|\leq |x-y|\cdot\sup_z \lvert g'(z)\rvert=:\phi(x-y,g').$$ But what about the general case? Has anyone an idea?

Comment: The same idea but, you use that for $\textbf{every}$ real numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
$$||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$$?

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I don't see the obvious.